# Pagination on an arrays of object in vuetify

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuetify.js

How do i make the pagination work in vuetify in an arrays of object?

I'm trying to add a pagination to the code. I want to display the regulatedEntities per object. It displays however it does not do a pagination. This the current code:

```
Vue Directory Component


User
<template>
  <div class="">
    <div v-if="entities">
      <div v-for="(item, index) in entities" :key="index">
        <v-card elevation="3" class="pa-4 ma-5">
          <h2 class="text-center mt-5 mb-5">{{ item.groupName }}</h2>
          <div class="d-flex justify-center mb-8">
            <AddEntity class="ml-3" :GName="item.groupName" />
          </div>
          <div class="">
            <Entities :entities="item.regulatedEntities.slice((page - 1) * itemsPerPage, page * itemsPerPage)"
              :GName="item.groupName" :regulatedEntities="item.regulatedEntities" />
            <v-pagination v-model="page" :length="Math.ceil(item.regulatedEntities.length / itemsPerPage)"
              :total-visible="7" items-per-page="9"></v-pagination>
          </div>
        </v-card>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Entities from '../entities/Entities.vue'
  import AddEntity from '@/components/dialogs/AddEntity.vue'
  import {
    getAllEntities,
  } from '@/components/entities/EntitiesService.js'

  export default {
    name: 'Directory',
    components: {
      Entities,
      AddEntity
    },
    data() {
      return {
        searchentity: '',
        fetch_status: "fetching",
        entities: [],
        GNname: "",
        GID: "",
        page: 1,
        currentPage: 1,
        itemsPerPage: 9,
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.getEntities();
    },
    computed: {
      pagedEntities() {
        const index = this.page - 1;
        const currentGroup = this.entities.find(
          (group) => group.groupName === this.selectedGroup
        );
        if (!currentGroup) {
          return [];
        }
        return currentGroup.regulatedEntities.slice(
          index * this.itemsPerPage,
          (index + 1) * this.itemsPerPage
        );
      },

    },
    methods: {
      getEntities() {
        getAllEntities().then(response => {
          this.entities = response
          this.fetch_status = "success"
        }).catch((error) => {
          this.fetch_status = "failed"
        });
      },
    },
    watch: {
      page(newPage) {
        this.currentPage = newPage;
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

I've tried various solutions but i still can't paginate it. I am expecting it to display the regulatedEntities according to its category or groupName. This is the data structure:

```
const entities = [{
    groupName: "Life",
    regulatedEntities: [{
        id: "1",
        logo: "ic-logo.png",
        license: "2021/01-R",
        companyName: "A",
        address: "United Nations Manila",
        email: "cispcorporateplanning@gmail.com",
        phone: "09871124551",
        inCharge: "Jihyo Park",
        designation: "Human Resource",
        amlOfficer: "Hayley Williams",
        alternateAml: "Selena Gomez",
        board: "Justin Bieber",
        updatedOn: "04/23/2023",
        updatedBy: "Taylor Swift",

      },
      {
        id: "2",
        license: "2021/01-R",
        logo: "cisp-logo.jpg",
        companyName: "B",
        address: "United Nations Manila",
        email: "cispcorporateplanning@gmail.com",
        phone: "09871124551",
        inCharge: "Jihyo Park",
        designation: "Human Resource",
        amlOfficer: "Hayley Williams",
        alternateAml: "Selena Gomez",
        board: "Justin Bieber",
        updatedOn: "04/23/2023",
        updatedBy: "Taylor Swift",
      },

      {
        id: "3",
        license: "2021/01-R",
        logo: "ic-logo.png",
        companyName: "C",
        address: "United Nations Manila",
        email: "cispcorporateplanning@gmail.com",
        phone: "09871124551",
        inCharge: "Jihyo Park",
        designation: "Human Resource",
        amlOfficer: "Hayley Williams",
        alternateAml: "Selena Gomez",
        board: "Justin Bieber",
        updatedOn: "04/23/2023",
        updatedBy: "Taylor Swift",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    groupName: "Non-Life",
    regulatedEntities: [{
        id: "4",
        logo: "ic-logo.png",
        license: "2021/01-R",
        companyName: "AA",
        address: "Chaftis Phils Manila",
        email: "cispcorporateplanning@gmail.com",
        phone: "09871124551",
        inCharge: "Jihyo Park",
        designation: "Human Resource",
        amlOfficer: "Hayley Williams",
        alternateAml: "Selena Gomez",
        board: "Justin Bieber",
        updatedOn: "04/23/2023",
        updatedBy: "Taylor Swift",

      },

      {
        id: "5",
        license: "2021/01-R",
        logo: "cisp-logo.jpg",
        companyName: "BB",
        address: "United Nations Manila",
        email: "cispcorporateplanning@gmail.com",
        phone: "09871124551",
        inCharge: "Jihyo Park",
        designation: "Human Resource",
        amlOfficer: "Hayley Williams",
        alternateAml: "Selena Gomez",
        board: "Justin Bieber",
        updatedOn: "04/23/2023",
        updatedBy: "Taylor Swift",
      },

      {
        id: "6",
        license: "2021/01-R",
        logo: "cisp-logo.jpg",
        companyName: "CC",
        address: "United Nations Manila",
        email: "cispcorporateplanning@gmail.com",
        phone: "09871124551",
        inCharge: "Jihyo Park",
        designation: "Human Resource",
        amlOfficer: "Hayley Williams",
        alternateAml: "Selena Gomez",
        board: "Justin Bieber",
        updatedOn: "04/23/2023",
        updatedBy: "Taylor Swift",
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    groupName: "Composite",
    regulatedEntities: [{
        id: "4",
        logo: "ic-logo.png",
        license: "2021/01-R",
        companyName: "AAA",
        address: "Chaftis Phils Manila",
        email: "cispcorporateplanning@gmail.com",
        phone: "09871124551",
        inCharge: "Jihyo Park",
        designation: "Human Resource",
        amlOfficer: "Hayley Williams",
        alternateAml: "Selena Gomez",
        board: "Justin Bieber",
        updatedOn: "04/23/2023",
        updatedBy: "Taylor Swift",

      },

      {
        id: "5",
        license: "2021/01-R",
        logo: "cisp-logo.jpg",
        companyName: "BBB",
        address: "United Nations Manila",
        email: "cispcorporateplanning@gmail.com",
        phone: "09871124551",
        inCharge: "Jihyo Park",
        designation: "Human Resource",
        amlOfficer: "Hayley Williams",
        alternateAml: "Selena Gomez",
        board: "Justin Bieber",
        updatedOn: "04/23/2023",
        updatedBy: "Taylor Swift",
      },

      {
        id: "6",
        license: "2021/01-R",
        logo: "cisp-logo.jpg",
        companyName: "CCC",
        address: "United Nations Manila",
        email: "cispcorporateplanning@gmail.com",
        phone: "09871124551",
        inCharge: "Jihyo Park",
        designation: "Human Resource",
        amlOfficer: "Hayley Williams",
        alternateAml: "Selena Gomez",
        board: "Justin Bieber",
        updatedOn: "04/23/2023",
        updatedBy: "Taylor Swift",
      }
    ],
  }
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Seems like you have a `v-pagination`, that gives you a page number, and then you use `.slice()` to get the corresponding page from your data. This is how it works. What goes wrong?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).